# feature_spec in TFdatasets with multiple response variables

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I'm looking to predict a set of responses using a common set of features using the tensorflow package in R. I've worked through a couple of single response regression examples, and am attempting to modify that code to accommodate my data. Here I'm using the hearts dataset to demonstrate.

```
library(keras)
library(tensorflow)
library(tfdatasets)
library(tfprobability)

data(hearts)
head(hearts)

hearts <- tensor_slices_dataset(hearts) %>% dataset_batch(32)

#This works
spec <- feature_spec(hearts, x = c(age, sex, cp, trestbps, chol, fbs, restecg, 
                                   exang, oldpeak, slope, ca, thal, thalach), 
                     y = target)

#This doesn't
spec <- feature_spec(hearts, x = c(age, sex, cp, trestbps, chol, fbs, restecg, 
                                   exang, oldpeak, slope, ca, thal, thalach), 
                     y = c(target, thalach))
```

So, how can I pass multiple response variables to feature_spec? It seems like this is possible in Python from this post (https://towardsdatascience.com/bayesian-neural-networks-with-tensorflow-probability-fbce27d6ef6).
See the code chunk under 'Data Handling'. Is this just not an option in R?